# Is there a way to turn off same origin policy on the crosswalk webview for certain iframes?

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

I'm using the crosswalk webview on a project. I need some javascript to access elements which are on an iframe from a different origin but the same origin policy throws an error. Is there a way on crosswalk to turn this security check off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crosswalk supports all command line option that Chromium has, so, to disable samle origin policy, you can use `--disable-web-security` switch.

If you are using `make_apk` tool to package your application, you can use the following option: `python make_apk.py --xwalk-command-line='--disable-web-security' ...`

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/use-chromium-command-lines-in-your-apps-on-android

Or if you are embedding Crosswalk WebView directly, you can just write a plain text file named `xwalk-command-line` into the `assets` of your project,  the content of the text file should be `walk --disable-web-security`.

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty cool. If I disable all web security though that might be a bit much, is it possible to just give some domain extra rights or something?